# API request should take User Object as input and update the user

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

The task is to create an API endpoint “/updateUser” for updating the user information.
The API request should take the User object as input and update the user.

My model is this:

```
class UserModel(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    dob = models.DateField(null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

Serializer is:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ['id','name','username','email','phone','password']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True}
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password !=None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

url is:

```
from django.urls import path
from . views import RegisterView, UpdateUserView
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', RegisterView.as_view()),
    path('updateUser/', UpdateUserView.as_view())
]
```

Now, how to create view for this which takes object as input and update it?!

Comment: please attach your view file too :)

Answer (score 1):

I think to it this way, you have to override the `update` method to handle update of the user, it will look like this

```
 def update(self, instance, validated_data):
     """Your code to handle it"""
     return instance
```

Your view should inherit from `UpdateAPIView` (Here you can check [the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#updateapiview) )
and then in your url file you should do it like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', RegisterView.as_view()),
    path('updateUser/', UpdateUserView.as_view())
]
```

To do this without passing the id in the url path (as it is not secure by itself so you will have to write some code for permission) you have to override the `get_object` function like this:

```
def get_object(self):
  queryset = self.get_queryset()
  obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, user=self.request.user)
  return obj
```

By doing this it is secure.

Ps. *"""Your code to handle it"""* is the code that you have to get the user and update its data based on what you want to do.

*Some other way to do it is by creating some function based view, but this one works too.*